# Exit after initializing batch script from java

Tags: java, process, batch-file, runtime

I want to initialize one batch script using java code. Once it is initialized I need to exit the java program and wants the batch script to continue executing. How can I achieve this. I used Runtime and Process to do this. But it is waiting for the batch script to finish before proceeding to the next. This is the sample program I tried out.

```
        try {
            Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
            System.out.println("Executing process");
            Process p = r.exec("c:\\anoop\\ping.bat");
            System.out.println("Executed process"); 
            p.waitFor();
            System.out.println("Exiting with out :: ");
        } catch (Exception e) {// Catch exception if any
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

If I use p.exitValue(), it is giving error java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: process has not exited. In short, I just want to initialize a batch script and then exit from the java program.

Thanks, Anoop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the exit value of the process, use:

```
int res = p.waitFor();
System.out.println("Exiting with out :: " + res);
```

If you want the process to just continue, don't wait for it (don't call `wait()`)

If the process expects input, or produces some output, you have to handle that (preferably on separate threads) since all I/O is redirected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this, but the problem is I wanted to execute one batch script, and if I am not giving waitFor() it is not getting executed. Is there any other way I can execute the batch script?

Comment: I think you should add to your command the following: "cmd /c start yourbatch.bat"

Comment: Hey, its not needed. i just figured it out. No need for cmd. Just need to add a mere sleep of 100 to thread. Thead.sleep(100) is enough. because the JVM will exit even before the command prompt is started. Thanks a lot for the help